# PowerBI рассылает необновлённые отчеты

Tags: powerbi

Настроена ежедневная рассылка репорта из PowerBI на email (стандартный набор - скриншот страницы + веб-ссылка на репорт). Сегодня - с обновленными за вчерашний день показателями (прибыль и др.метрики).

---

Рассылка происходит через полчаса после обновления датасета, на котором построен репорт. Обновление датасета происходит без перебоев, данные за вчерашний день поялвяются как и положено.  При просмотре репорта с сервиса powerbi - всё хорошо, все данные есть.

---

Наблюдается следующая проблема:
 в скриншоте страницы репорта в рассылке - по временным фильтрам видно, что данные за вчера есть, но все таблицы и графики показывают данные только за позавчера. 
Проблема исчезает, если руками перед рассылкой зайти в репорт --> режим редактирования --> нажать "Обновить" --> Сохранить.  В этом случае скриншот приходит с актуальными данными

---

Как можно исправить эту проблему и сделать так, чтобы автоматом, а не после ручного вмешательства, происходила рассылка скриншота с актуальными данными?